# How to create a network using a command line script?

Tags: multisite, wp-cli, testing, docker

I would like to run UI automated tests for my WordPress plugin. I am using Docker to run a WP instance and it runs my tests, that is fine. I am using `wp-cli` to install and config a testing site.

I would also like to run the test suite on multisite. For that, I need to setup a network. I know how to install a multisite network manually, but I need a command which I add to my Dockerfile. So my question is: Is there a way how to create a multisite network using command line script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using WP-CLI, I recommend you to use the [`wp core multisite-install`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-install/) command to set up your network installation.

When you check out the documentation you'll see that it's pretty straightforward. Here's the example from the docs:

```
$ wp core multisite-install --title="Welcome to the WordPress" \
> --admin_user="admin" --admin_password="password" \
> --admin_email="user@example.com"
Single site database tables already present.
Set up multisite database tables.
Added multisite constants to wp-config.php.
Success: Network installed. Don't forget to set up rewrite rules.
```

You can perfectly use this command to set everything up in your Docker environment.